# Can you hault OnCreate until button from alert dialogue is pressed?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am almost done with release 1 of my app and am doing finishing touches to it.  However I am stuck with a Dialog Box for the user to accept the EULA before they can continue using the app.

I put the alertdialogue call in OnCreate method.  This works beautifully, when the app opens up for the first time or on an update they are shown a modal alert box with an accept of decline button.  If they hit decline, the app closes, if they hit accept, the dialog gets dismissed and the already initial activity is shown.

What I am looking to do is have teh alert box show (in oncreate) and then not load anything else until either the ACCEPT or CANCEL button is pressed.

do I use stop() and resume()?  I'm lost.

Shawn Mulligan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it almost right, only thing that's missing is:
1) Adding the user selection in a preference so that in case the user selection accept you won't show the dialog over and over again.
2) having an If condition in which based on the preference if the user has not accepted the terms and conditions show the dialog again or call the required method which trigger navigation, API etc. Also for the first time is the user selects a positive option call the required methods from the callback of the alert dialog

Comment: I left that part out, because I thought it was irrelevant, but I have it writing to the shared a key that is generated based on version, so that way once the user accepts the EULA, the only time it will show agaiin is if they download an update.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in onCreate.

```
case R.id.dialog_button_accept:// ACCEPT 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // do other things
    break;
case R.id.dialog_button_cancel:// CANCEL 
    finish();// finish this activity
    break;
```

Comment: This sounds all so logical, however I have the Eula dialog open from another class and in a file of it's own, which is called from the OnCreate method.  So can I put the setContentView, in the accept portion in that class file, instead of in the onCreate after the call to the Eula?

Comment: try this   `mActivity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in your onClick method

Answer (score 0):

I have a seperate class for displaying the Eula and generating and storing the key.  Here is the code for the positive and negative button in the class:

```
 @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            // Mark this version as read.
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
                            editor.commit();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Close the activity as they have declined the EULA
                            mActivity.finish();
                        }

                    });
```

Here is the code for activity main OnCreate Method

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                new SimpleEula(this).show();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                //loading the default fragment
                loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
```

The overall goal is to show the EULA and pause the rest of the onCreate until a decision has been made while the EULA is showing.  So using solution posted, is there a way to recover and save the positive button press and pass it back over to OnCreate and then use the switch statement from the solution posted above?

Comment: Why not just have the EULA as the launcher activity and check your saved key, if the user has accepted that then navigate him to the main activity

Comment: So I looked into it and tried playing around with the code with out having to rewrite the whole blasten thing and can not seem to figure out what exactly I need to do to get it to work.  What I did do and so far didn't get no where was created a new class ShowEula  and then in the onCreate method moved the code over from MainActivity to Load ShowEula();  All was fine and dandy, until it came to closing current activity and opening new.  startActivity isn't recognized and a few other things that I tried.  Let alone changing the manifest file.

Comment: what exactly happened? @Shwan

Comment: I updated the new code above and all I get is a black and white flashing screen.  
 So I just did another test and commented out the 2 lines for starting the new intent.  Intent intent2=new Intent(ShowEula.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent2);  and the EULA SHOWS with the accept and cancel button.  So what is wrong with my 2 lines to start the new activity??@war_Hero

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to successfuly edit all of my code and when I went to launch it, it just flases black to white.  Not sure what I did wrong here.

Manifest File (Think maybe the issue is there)

```
<activity android:name=".ShowEula">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

ShowEula is the new class I created.

ShowEula

```
package com.app.restaurant.bowzers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class ShowEula extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new SimpleEula(this).show();
        Intent intent2=new Intent(ShowEula.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
       }
}
```

Just as before

```
new SimpleEula(this).show();
```

Is suppose to load the Check and Or Display Eula.  Then the startActivity to load the original MainActivity.

The end results a flashing black to white screen app.

Not exactly sure where I went wrong.

Comment: try setContent and display xml in Activity

Comment: its not difficult it is difficult to help without the complete info, is there any error in logcat

Comment: What I am not understaing why is the app still loading or trying to load MainActivity before the positive and or negative listener is activated??

Comment: can you create the alert dialog also in the samme activity

Comment: oh thats simple you are doing start activity after this line new SimpleEula(this).show();

Comment: if you move those 2 lines to the inside of the click of positive button your problem should be solved

Comment: I thought it was just simple as well but I get errors with the startActivity line.  I tried that initially by just removing it from the MainActivity to the button positive.  So yeah,  just not sure why this is so hard.  I wish that I could just do the following fter the alert dialog is called pause the on create method til button is selected.  I am fighting with this just for the aesthetics of it all.  I don't mind that you can see the app behind the dialog and it is non responsive because I used .setCancelable(false).  I would just prefer not seeing any of the app til the EULA was accepted.

Comment: have code that implements the In-App Update?  Or any code that checks on launch if your version is different than google play one and if so download the update else just keep running the app?

Comment: hey can you post the 2 activities and manifest, and the Alert dialog code that you have in your aapp

Answer (score 0):

SimpleEula.Java

```
package com.app.restaurant.bowzers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;

import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getSystemServiceName;
import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;


public class SimpleEula {

    private String EULA_PREFIX = "eula_";
    private Activity mActivity;





    public SimpleEula(Activity context) {
        mActivity = context;
    }

    private PackageInfo getPackageInfo() {
        PackageInfo pi = null;
        try {
            pi = mActivity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mActivity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pi;
    }

    public void show() {
        PackageInfo versionInfo = getPackageInfo();

        // the eulaKey changes every time you increment the version number in the AndroidManifest.xml
        final String eulaKey = EULA_PREFIX + versionInfo.versionCode;
        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
        boolean hasBeenShown = prefs.getBoolean(eulaKey, false);
        if(hasBeenShown == false){

            // Show the Eula
            String title = mActivity.getString(R.string.app_name) + " v" + versionInfo.versionName;

            //Includes the updates as well so users know what changed.
            String message = mActivity.getString(R.string.updates) + "\n\n" + mActivity.getString(R.string.eula);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            // Mark this version as read.
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
                            editor.commit();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();

                                               }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Close the activity as they have declined the EULA
                            mActivity.finish();
                        }

                    });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.restaurant.bowzers">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!--Maps Api Key-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="API_KEY_FOR_MAPS"/>
    </application>
    <uses-feature
        android:required="true"
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.Java - MainActivity OnCreate Method

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                new SimpleEula(this).show();


                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                //loading the default fragment
                loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
                //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener

                BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
                navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        }
```

The overall goal was to stop everything from loading until they agree to the EULA.  As the code stands, which is really not a big issue, but it does bother me, the EULA does load, but behind the MODAL Dialogue Box the inital fragment loads, instead of it being a white background with nothing and no bottom navigation.